# Can't save values of variable through header files

Tags: c++, struct, nodes

I have declared a struct in a header A file. I assigned a value to a variable of that type struct on the same A file. 
I included the A.h file on the other B.h file that is going to run the code.

For some reason, when I try to access the value of the the variable, it always resets. Is there a problem with my code or is this a reference issue?

Since I'm doing structures, I want the first node of the structure to always be the same (void option 1) I tried using extern but that doesn't help.

A.h file

```
using namespace std;


struct nodeChar
{
    char character;
    struct nodeChar *next;
    struct nodeChar *previous;
};

extern nodeChar *firstChar = new nodeChar();
extern nodeChar *previousChar = new nodeChar();
extern nodeChar *sentinelCharacter = new nodeChar();

void addCharacterNode(nodeChar *newCharacter)
{

    sentinelCharacter = firstChar;

    if(firstChar->character == NULL)
    {
        firstChar = newCharacter;
    }
    else while(sentinelCharacter != NULL)
    {
        if(sentinelCharacter->next = NULL)
        {
            newCharacter->previous = sentinelCharacter;
            sentinelCharacter->next = newCharacter;
            break;
        }

        sentinelCharacter = sentinelCharacter->next;
    }
}
```

B.h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "TextStructure.h"
#include <curses.h>

void option1()
{
    printMenuOption1();
    int x = 1;
    int y = 7;
    bool keepWriting = TRUE;
    nodeChar *pressedCharacter = new nodeChar();

    while(keepWriting)
    {
        int key = getch();

        switch(key)
        {
            case '9':
                keepWriting = FALSE;
                clear();
                break;
            case '8':
                saveFile();
                printMenuOption1();
                break;
            case '7':

                break;

            default:
                pressedCharacter->character = key;
                addCharacterNode(pressedCharacter);
                mvprintw(y, x, "%c", firstChar->character); /*This is where it prints a character. 
It prints the key pressed. But when I write again, it should still print the first character, not the key pressed. And it prints the key pressed. */

                if(x == 68)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y++;
                } else
                {
                    x++;
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully I posted the question correctly. Not a pro on c++, any tip is well received.

Comment: Here's the first tip that comes to mind after reading the above: functions do not belong in `.h` files.

Comment: Alright, it would be on the .cpp file I'm assuming? Can I include the .cpp file on my main.cpp file? I just had a lot of trouble with the .cpp and the .h files. so I try to write it all on the .h files. Thanks for that.

Comment: No, `.cpp` files should not be included from other `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 0):

First:
The code is written in assumption that 'next' and 'previous' will get assigned NULL when structure is alocated by operator 'new'. Normally it's not the case, if these pointer are not explicitely assigned NULL, then they get a random values. You need to assign 'next' and 'previous' NULL values after 'new'.

Second:
You allocate 'pressedCharacter' only once, before loop:

```
bool keepWriting = TRUE;
**nodeChar *pressedCharacter = new nodeChar();**
```

So you always assign character to the same structure. The bold line should be inside the loop.

Comment: Omaigawdd! This sorted it out, I appreciate it very much Dmitry! Also, assigning the values to the next and previous is useful as well, thanks for that.